# Cutting Rows Based On a Cell Value And Paste On Top of Specific Row

Tags: vba, excel, loops, copy-paste

I have a list of people who have departments ranging from 3811-3933.

I'm trying to sort everything so that at the top of the list are all the employees with the dept numbers 3831 until 3843, then a blank row and then everyone else. Since the rows appear in department order, the loop can stop once it reaches department 3844. So far this is what I've come up with, but it doesn't work.

If possible, I would also like to take the rows with department 3827 and paste that at the bottom of the top half (3831-3843)

The rows of people start at row 6 and the department is in column D

```
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To a
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value >= 3831# And 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value < 3844# Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Cut
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Delete
    [enter image description here][1]
End If
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4) = 3844#
Next

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

After playing around with SJR's answer, I've come up with this code. The problem is that all the cells at the bottom are cut and pasted in reverse order, so it's now largest to smallest instead of smallest to largest.

```
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
a = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For i = a To 6 Step -1
    If .Cells(i, 4).Value < 3831# Or .Cells(i, 4).Value >= 3844# Then
        .Rows(i).Cut .Cells(a + 2, 1)
        .Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next
End With
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @SJR It takes some of the rows that I want to put on the top and mixes them all around so now the departments are out of order.

Comment: Why can't you just sort the data? If there is no logical order can you assign a number to each department and then sort on that?

Comment: @SJR because I need departments that are in between to go to the top and the rest to go to the bottom

Comment: I'm having trouble visualising - can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Also not sure about this line `Cells(i, 4) = 3844#` which is outside your If so every single column D entry will end up as 3844.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, but I still can't quite get my head round what you are trying to do.

```
Sub x()

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    a = .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = a To 6 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 4).Value >= 3831# And .Cells(i, 4).Value < 3844# Then
            .Rows(i).Cut .Cells(a + 1, 1)
            .Rows(i).Delete
            .Cells(i, 4) = 3844#
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I was forgetting a cardinal rule that when deleting rows always loop backwards so this may work better.

Comment: Would it make more sense to make a range based on the dept cell value, cut and paste that range at the top, add a row and all the rest are at the bottom?

Comment: It's not exactly what I need, but it's enough to work off. Thanks!